# How can I transform this curl command into php curl code?

Tags: php, curl

I struggle everytime I need to use php curl. The documentation is pretty bad and I endup doing trial and error. How can I convert this console command into php curl code:

```
curl -H "X-Futuresimple-Token: token" "https://appointments.futuresimple.com/api/v1/appointments.json"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array( 'X-Futuresimple-Token: token' ) );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://appointments.futuresimple.com/api/v1/appointments.json' );

$result = curl_exec( $curl );

if ( $result === false ) {
    die( 'Error fetching data: ' . curl_error( $curl ) );
}

curl_close( $curl );
```